# Rust double mut borrow in loops

Tags: rust, borrow

Looking for a way to push in both Vec<Vec<>> and it's inner Vec<>. I do understand why it fails, but still struggle to find some graceful way to solve it.

```
fn example() {
    let mut vec: Vec<Vec<i32>> = vec![];
    vec.push(vec![]);
    for i in &mut vec {
        i.push(1);
        if vec.len() < 10 {
            vec.push(vec![]); // second mut borrow
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect to have inside the `vec` in the end? Taken literally, this loop should either never start (if the outer vector is empty, as it is here), or never end, since at each iteration you'd be adding a new item to be iterated over.

Comment: You cannot add elements to a vec while iterating over it. Can you provide more context, what you are actually trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The borrow checker won't allow you to iterate over a vector by reference and modify it during iteration. The reason for that is that modifying the vector can reallocate its storage, which would invalidate the references used for iteration. (And there is also the question of what it means to iterate over a changing vector, do you want to visit the elements added during iteration or just the elements that were present originally.)

The easiest fix that allows you to do what you want is to just iterate the vector using an index:

```
fn example() {
    let mut vec: Vec<Vec<i32>> = vec![];
    vec.push(vec![]);
    let mut ind = 0;
    while ind < vec.len() {
        let i = &mut vec[ind];
        i.push(1);
        if vec.len() < 10 {
            vec.push(vec![]);
        }
        ind += 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of manually incrementing the `ind` variable, it might be more readable to use a regular for-loop: `for ind in 0..(vec.len().max(10))`, where the argument to `max` determines the length of the outter vector after the loop.

Comment: @sebpuetz Thanks, that would work too. I wanted to provide the most general version that would work regardless of how many elements are added to the vector inside the loop body.